# How to create pagination based on client.Search results Elasticsearch Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, pagination, nest

Is there any way in which I can retrieve all the results from client.Search (I think this can be done using `scroll API`) and create a pagination for these results when displaying them? Is there any API from ES for doing so?

Or using `From()` and `size()`, can it be done?

For eg: Lets say, I have 100,000 documents on the index and when I search for a keyword it generates some 200 results. How can I use scroll, from and size to show them?

TIA

Comment: `from` and `size` can be used to paginate

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/from-and-size-usage.html

Comment: @RussCam Thanks Russ. I already had a look at this link. But I'm just thinking how to loop through other results. Does it mean that I have to run the query everytime i click on the page number. Like if I click on page 2 , then it should run a query for from 11 to size 10 and so on?Will that not affect the performance of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `from` and `size` options to implement pagination for Elasticsearch results. 
The code snippet can be something like below:

```
def query(page)
  size = 10
  page ||= 1
  from = (page-1) * size 

  # elasticsearch query with from * size options
end
```

You may need to know total number of results to implement pagination without sending a additional count request. To get the total results, you can use the `total` field of the response.

**=== Updated**

If you want to get the search results of the first page, then you can use `query(1)`. If you want to get the search results of the second page, then you can use `query(2)` and so on.

The purpose of the `scroll` is slightly different. Let's say you need to get all records of the search results and the number of results are too large (eg., millions of results). If you retrieve all the data at once, it will arise a kind of memory issue or problems because of the high load. In this case, you can use `scroll` to fetch results step by step.

For the pagination, you don't need to get all data of the search results. You only need to get `some` data of a specific page. In this case, you may need to use just `query` with `from` and `size` options NOT `scroll`.

Comment: Thanks Jeon. I updated by question. Can you please have a look at it once.

Comment: @Jeon Thank you. But we use `scroll` to fetch all the results right? like a search query returns 50 results, on the first page if i want to display the first 10 (sorted based on score) and on the second page next 10  and so on.. In this case we use `scroll` also right? Am I following you correctly?

Comment: @ASN If your search query returns 50 results, and you want to display the first 10 results on the first page and the next 10 for the second page, then you need to use `query` with `from` and `size` options.
On the other hand, let's say you want to store whole search results into MySQL table. In this case you need to retrieve whole search results and load it into the memory at once. It will cause memory issue or something else. In this case you can use `scroll` to fetch and process the search results step by step.

Comment: Oh Okok..Got it!!! So in my case I don't have to get all the results at once instead use from and size and display all the documents.. Am I correct?

Comment: @ASN Yes exactly. You only need to get 10 results(for example) at once using `from` and `size` options. To implement pagination, you don't need to care about `scroll`.